# Powershell Return only TRUE if All Values are the same

Tags: powershell

I have the script below to read registry values from a certain key(taking no credit for it). My end goal is to only return TRUE if all the values in the array Match. However I'm not quite getting it as

[Example Registry Entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Os13G.png)

```
$array = @()
$regval = Get-Item -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Runner\Event
$regval.GetValueNames() | 
ForEach-Object {
$name = $_
        $rv.Value
        $array += New-Object psobject -Property @{'Value' = $rv.Value }
}

$Matchvalue = 'A'

Foreach ($v in $array){
if ($v -match $Matchvalue){
$true
}
}
```

Update: I've just tried again and it appears my array is empty. So any tips welcome for me.

Comment: Note that `-match 'A'` will give you all the values that contain an `'A'`, if you want to match the whole string, you should use `-match '^A$'`, or simply `-eq 'A'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
$regkey = Get-Item HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Runner\Event
$matchPattern = 'A'

$values = $regkey.GetValueNames()
$matchingValues = $values | Where { $regkey.GetValue($_) -match $matchPattern }

# this is going to be true or false
$values.Count -eq $matchingValues.Count
```

Note that by default, Powershell is case-insensitive. So `$matchPattern = 'A'` and `$matchPattern = 'a'` will behave the same.

Comment: Using your own comment @js2010, you could also do: `!($regkey.GetValueNames().ForEach{ $regkey.GetValue($_) } -NotMatch $matchPattern)`

Comment: @iRon Yes, there are many ways. I actually thought about using `.Where()` or `.ForEach()` but I decided to stick to more a "PowerShell idiomatic" style and use a pipeline.

Comment: That was not the point that I wanted to make (you could also use `Foreach-Object`). What I was trying to point out is (rather than using the [`.count`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13752) property) that "*all properties are the same*"  is the equal to "*not any property is different*".

Comment: @iRon I understand that. I wouldn't have written a comment making this very argument if I didn't.

Comment: Thank you - Will give the suggestions a try and report back asap.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt to do something like Haskell's "all".

```
function foldr ($sb, $accum, $list) {
  if ($list.count -eq 0) { $accum }
  else { & $sb $list[0] (foldr $sb $accum $list[1..$list.length]) }
}

function and ($list) {
  foldr { $args[0] -and $args[1] } $true $list
}

function all ($list, $sb) { 
  and ( $list | foreach $sb ) 
}


all 1,1,1 { $_ -eq 1 }
True

all 1,2,1 { $_ -eq 1 }
False
```

Comment: Too complicated. PowerShell's operators already work on lists. You can do `$listOfValues -notmatch 'pattern'` to get those values that don't match, and `-not ($listOfValues -notmatch 'pattern')` to make sure that all values match. `1,1,1,2 -eq 1` is `1,1,1`. `1,2,1,2 -ne 1` is `2,2`. `-not (1,1,1,1 -ne 1)` is `True`. `-not (1,2,1,2 -ne 1)` is `False`